# YESDIR = $(shell echo $(@:yes-%=%) | tr a-z A-Z)

Tags: gnu-make

I see this command in the makefile. Can someone give some explanation about this command? Especially:  `$(@:yes-%=%)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs):

> A *substitution reference* substitutes the value of a variable with alterations that you specify. It has the form `‘$(var:a=b)’` (or `‘${var:a=b}’`) and its meaning is to take the value of the variable *var*, replace every *a* at the end of a word with *b* in that value, and substitute the resulting string.
>
> Another type of substitution reference lets you use the full power of the `patsubst` function. It has the same form `‘$(var:a=b)’` described above, except that now *a* must contain a single `‘%’` character. This case is equivalent to `‘$(patsubst a,b,$(var))’`. See [Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions), for a description of the `patsubst` function.

So your example is stripping a leading `yes-` off the of value of `$@` (the current target).

Comment: Thanks very much! I got that.